# How to maintain user state in ext JS?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

I am trying to maintain user state in ext JS application, like we use session.
I want to maintain user state in my Ext JS/Sencha apllication. How I do.?
I want to keep UserId which i want to access globally in my application.

Comment: Create a singleton class with setters and getters ,set the user data on launch and access it across the application using your singleton class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Ext.define('UserInfo',{
    singelton: true,
    userInfo: {},
    setUserInfor: function(data){
       this.userInfo = data;
    },
    getUserInfo: function(){
     return this.userInfo;
    }
})
```

UserInfo class can be access accross the application.

Comment: where I should place this Code in my app?

Comment: In your app.js page